# How to display \ in android textview?

Tags: android

I am familiar with using \n in a textview to display on the second line, however I want to display the / in my textview.  I get the escape errors in eclipse when trying to display "C:\directorya\directoryb\"  is there a code I should be using to display \ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `\\`. One `\` escapes the second, so it displays a `\` character.